# css:after not working when element created by jquery

Tags: jquery, html, css

I am confused about why the CSS is not working on this HTML:

```
  <div class="append"></div>
  <button type="submit" onclick="submit()"></button>
```

JavaScript :

```
function submit(){
  var str="<div class='agent'>"
  str +="<div class='col-md-3 disabledagent' >"
  str +="<div class='disabled-agent-label'><span><b>Disabled</b></span></div>"
  str += "<div class='agent-name col-md-6'>"
  str += "<span class='agent-ip'>Jhony test</span>";
  str += "</div>";      
  str +="</div>"
  str +="</div>"
  $(".append").append(str)
}
```

and my CSS is:

```
.disabledagent {
  position: relative; 
  margin-bottom:15px;
}
.disabledagent::after { 
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.5;
  position:absolute; 
}

.disabled-agent-label {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30%;
}
```

My problem is that my `.disabledagent::after` is not working. I mean I'm not making `opacity 0.5`, can anyone tell me what I'm doing wrong?

Comment: You're not adding any content to the DOM, only creating a HTML string..? Even if you did append the string, the `:after` pseudo element has no content, so there's nothing to show at `0.5` opacity anyway...

Comment: you somply applied opacity to an empty element positionned .. you will see nothing

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan sorry i added jquery append still same

Comment: I added an answer for you below. You need to actually place some content in the `:after`

Comment: @RoryMcCrossan i want whole div whose class name =agent-name to be disable i mean opacity 0.5 and disabled should have opacity 1 (clas=disabled-agent-label)]

Comment: if you want :after without any content then specify height and width to it.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

i solve my issue by adding code like below and thanks for help @RoryMcCrossan and @Chill007

```
 .disabledagent {
   position: relative; 
   margin-bottom:15px;
 }
 .disabledagent::after {
   content: "";
   position: absolute;
   width: 100%;
   height: 100%;
   top: 0;
   left: 0;
   background-color: rgba(213, 218, 222, 0.75);
 }     

 .disabled-agent-label {

     z-index: 10;
     position: absolute;
     height: 100%;
     width: 100%;
     text-align: center;
     padding-top: 30%;
 }
```

Answer (score 2):

There's two issues here. Firstly you create a HTML string but don't do anything with it; you need to add it to the DOM, presumably by appending it to `.append`.

Secondly, the `:after` pseudo element you create has no content, so nothing appears to be faded. You need to set the `content` to be displayed in the element, something like this:

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var str = '<div class="agent">';
  str += '<div class="col-md-3 disabledagent">';
  str += '<div class="disabled-agent-label"><span><b>Disabled</b></span></div>';
  str += '<div class="agent-name col-md-6">';
  str += '<span class="agent-ip">Jhony test</span>';
  str += '</div></div></div>';
  $('.append').append(str);
});
```

```css
.disabledagent {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.disabledagent::after {
  content: "This content will be 0.5 opacity";
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
}

.disabled-agent-label {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="append"></div>
<button type="submit">Append...</button>
```

Finally, note that I changed your logic to use an unobtrusive event handler. You should not be using `on*` event attributes at all.

Answer (score 1):

you can try something like this

```js
$('button').on('click', function() {
  var str = '<div class="agent">';
  str += '<div class="col-md-3 disabledagent">';
  str += '<div class="disabled-agent-label"><span><b>Disabled</b></span></div>';
  str += '<div class="agent-name col-md-6">';
  str += '<span class="agent-ip">Jhony test</span>';
  str += '</div></div></div>';
  $('.append').append(str);
});
```

```css
.disabledagent {
  position: relative;
  margin-bottom: 15px;
}

.disabledagent::after {
  content: "";
  opacity: 0.5;
  position: absolute;
  width: 50%;
  height: 100%;
  top: 0;
  left: 0;
  background: red;
}

.disabled-agent-label {
  z-index: 10;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  text-align: center;
  padding-top: 30%;
}
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="append"></div>
<button type="submit">Append...</button>
```

Comment: @Chill007 you code working for background color but it still having opacity 1

Comment: no you can check by inspecting it is showing opacity 0.5 for background color